# Use middle click to have multiple cursors in Visual Studio 2019 like in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts

In **Visual Studio Code** you can drag with the middle mouse button to create multiple cursors.

[image: Multi cursor editing in VSCode]

I know you can have somewhat the same behaviour in Visual Studio 2019 using <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>LMB</kbd> .

**QUESTION: Is there any way to configure Visual studio to use the middle mouse button (without the alt key) instead?**

I have years of using VSCode so it's difficult for me to adapt my mind to a new shortcut.

Thanks!